# How can I use webdriver based on user input in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a python code that should get into a website based on the user input but every time I run the code, I get an error.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def getExample():
    word = input("Enter the word: ")
    driver.get("https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/"+str(word))
    sentences = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('entence component')
    print("examples : ")
    for i in sentences:
        print(driver.find_element_by_class_name(i).text)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/.....py", line 27, in <module>
>     getExample()
>   File "/Users/.....py", line 18, in getExample
>     word = input("Enter the word: ")
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> NameError: name 'hi' is not defined
> ```

Comment: The code is incomplete. The code you showed does not produce this error. Can you post more code please? For example the entire function `getExample()` would be good to see

Comment: Check it now plaese

Comment: I tried and it does not produce any errors. It just does not print any examples. However the error suggests that you are trying to use a undefined variable named 'hi' somewhere. are you trying to enter hi somewhere?

Comment: yes, I wrote hi when it asked for the 'word' input and It gave me an error, but It actually gives me an error on every word I write as an input.

Comment: that is weird... I do not get that error. Do you call the program in a command line?

Comment: u mean the application I use to run the program? I use pycharm

Comment: Try running it from the terminal in pycharm.

Comment: I got an error again

Comment: File "englishwords.py", line 28, in <module>
    getExample()
  File "englishwords.py", line 18, in getExample
    word = input("Enter the word: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Entrepreneur' is not defined

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what is causing the error. The code you posted works fine for me. Except the part where you get the examples.

Comment: How did u run the program? on teminal? I would try doing what u did it might work.

Comment: I used a terminal. I ran `python main.py` (only my file name for testing) It opened a browser and visited the desired page after entering a word

Comment: Hi @3jx could you specify what Python version you are on? If you're unsure, go to your command terminal and enter `python -V` or `python --version`

Comment: it is 2.7.18, how can I update it?

Comment: To begin, please read everything before updating. To update you will need to download and install a new version of Python from https://www.python.org/downloads/ (I'd recommend the most recent version). However, be aware that a lot of syntax has changed between Python 2 and Python 3, so if you have a lot of code written in Python2, it might not work as expected or at all. However, it should work in your version if you change `input()` to `raw_input()` as that has been changed and you're using Python 3 lexicon.

Comment: I'll try downloading it right now thanks